# Resultados en forma de url y no el nombre de la tabla MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

El problema es que cuándo realizo un búsqueda, me arroja un resultado pero no se visualiza de la manera que yo espero.

Cuándo realizo la consulta en el servidor local, me arroja el resultado esperado:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'pagos';
+------------+
| TABLE_NAME |
+------------+
| pagos      |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.66 sec)
```

La misma consulta ahora en phpMyAdmin donde tengo mi sitio:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'pagos'
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| sql.php?table=pagos&amp;token=78563b6e7a9ac860275976a5c2c841f5 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

La consulta está bien realizada porque obviamente me arroja el mismo resultado pero no entiendo por qué me arroja la url y no el nombre de la tabla.

La siguiente imagen ejemplifica el error que yo tengo, no sólo es en la columna `TABLES.TABLE_NAME`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este mismo problema lo tengo en las otras tablas

```
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

No sé si sea un problema grave, o muy sencillo pero ya me demoré bastante en buscar una solución, tanto que estoy pensando en eliminar toda la base de datos y crear otra, tal vez así se solucione. Pero no me es tan fácil tomar el camino sencillo y quedarme con la duda de la posible solución.

Espero que ustedes puedan apoyarme como en otras ocasiones.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: La imagen que has puesto sirve de poco, no se ve nada... Pero, ¿cuál es la finalidad de esa consulta? ¿Tu base de datos está alojada en un hosting compartido o algo así?

Comment: La imagen es un `ejemplo` y la encontré en otro sitio web sin repuestas a ese post y describe exactamente el problema que yo tengo, y la finalidad de esta consulta sencilla es para ejemplificar mi problema, ya que utilizo las tablas que contiene `information_schema` para muchas otras cosas pero deseo que me arroje los nombres de las tablas y columnas como en mi servidor local y no unas URLs. Y sí, es un Hosting compartido. ¡Gracias!.

Comment: Con respecto a la imagen, puedes copiar la url y pegarla en otra pestaña para que se visualice de tamaño completo.

Answer (score 0):

El resultado que estás obteniendo puede que sea debido a algún bug en PHPMyAdmin, o a  que éste no está actualizado, o a restricciones del hosting. Lo cierto es que una consulta que revele el token de conexión podría ser peligrosa.

Propondría las siguientes alternativas:

### Opción 1

Si sólo te interesa el nombre de la tabla:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE '%prueba%';
```

Te traerá todas las tablas que contengan la palabra `prueba` en el nombre.

---

### Opción 2

Si te interesa más información de la tabla:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name='prueba';
```

O:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE '%prueba%';
```

Esta consulta te traerá más información sobre la tabla. [Aquí puedes ver una explicación más detallada sobre ello](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html).

Nótese que ninguna de estas consultas revelan las tablas internas del manejador, lo cual las hace más seguras que el uso de `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

---

### Opción 3

Si aún lo que te interesa es usar la consulta como la tienes originalmente. Podrías:

- a. Crear un script (mediante PHP o el lenguaje de servidor que estés usando), lanzar la consulta desde allí y mostrar los resultados donde los necesite.
- b. Contactar con el servicio técnico del hosting donde está alojada la base de datos. Quizá sea necesario que actualicen la versión de PHPMyAdmin que tienen.
- c. Podrías también probar con una base de datos distinta, si la tuvieras, para depurar que no es un problema de la base de datos en sí.

Comment: Tengo otro hosting con la misma empresa donde contraté, consulté la base de datos de ahí y es exactamente igual, lo cual indica que es un problema de configuración (al menos eso creo), voy a contactar con servicio técnico, yo lo ocupo mucho para filtrar índices, claves foráneas, etc, mi problema no son las consultas, ni como hacerlas, es más bien la forma en que se muestran los resultados y los comandos que me dices los ocupo bastante también. ¡Muchas gracias por la información y el tiempo!.